# How to make simple nav menu keyboard accessible?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have a simple `ul` menu

```
<ul role="menu" aria-label="menu">
    <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" ><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">item 1</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" ><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">item 2</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" ><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">item 3</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" ><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can navigate with up with tab and down tab + shift. But how to make it accessible with keyboard arrows so users can navigate up and down?

Comment: Be careful, by adding `role=menu` you are telling the user that he/she can expect it behave like an OS menu. You also *have* to make it keyboard accessible and should follow the pattern outlined in the [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1 for menu](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here a working example with your code :
http://plnkr.co/edit/UeUEIvO4hKzsdlhSTdNg?p=preview

```
<body>
  <ul role="menu" aria-label="menu">
      <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" ><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">item 1</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" ><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">item 2</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" ><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">item 3</a></li>
      <li role="menuitem" tabindex="0" ><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">item 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).keydown(
    function(e)
    {    
        //38 is the keycode for arrow up
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {  
          //check if a li is focused, if not it focus the first one    
          if($('li').is(':focus')){
            $("li:focus").next().focus();
          }
          else{
            $("li:first-child").focus();
          }

        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 40) {      
          if($('li').is(':focus')){
            $("li:focus").prev().focus();
          }
          else{
            $("li:first-child").focus();
          }
        }
    }
);
</script>
```

There is a list of the differents keycodes : https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Working as expected, but can I do this without js? I was thinking specific role, tabindex, etc can achieve the same without js. Am I wrong?

Comment: With tabindex you can choose in which order the elements will be focusing by pressing "tab" with only html, but if you want to use the arrows you have to use javascript

Comment: Just to back up your original intent and @grogro's comment: arrow keys for navigating a menu is definitely preferred to having to tab through each menu option. [Simply Accessible did an article about this and has provided some code to help out](http://simplyaccessible.com/article/arrow-key-navigation/)

Comment: See my comment above. Using `role=menu` means you should support more than just arrow keys, but also Home, End, and Escape. See the [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#menu) for menu.